# HTA xss weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, xss, hta

I have chosen HTA to make a small website because it allegedly ignores the Same Origin Policy. To test this I have written a small test site with these 4 iframes:

iframe id="google" src="http://www.google.nl" application="yes">
iframe id="test" src="test.html">
iframe id="test2" src="C:/test.html">
iframe id="test3" src="D:/test/test.html">

The content is accuratly displayed for all four iframes. However when I use JS to get the body of the iframes, I run into a weird problem:

$(document).ready(function() {
alert($("#google").contents().find("body").html());
alert($("#test").contents().find("body").html());
alert($("#test2").contents().find("body").html());
alert($("#test3").contents().find("body").html());
});

The alert for all test id-s works as it's  supposed to. The one for #google however, returns undefined.

The main file i'm running the HTA from is in C:/some/directory/deep/in/test.hta

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've maybe misunderstood the [security policy of the HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Security). Using `application=yes` allows the code *in the `iframe`* to access the main window, but you can't access a cross-origin `iframe` document, even using HTA. Just think what would happen, if it was possible!

Only advice I can give is: ***never*** set `application=yes` for third party `iframe`s (or `frame`s) in HTA. It's really dangerous, the code in `iframe` can do anything it wants within your machine.